# When I create a tenant and specify `drop_after` it doesn't pass the

Tags: cnosdb

When I create a tenant and specify `drop_after` it doesn't go through:

```sql
create tenant test_tenant with drop_after = '7d';
```

Returns results:

```
{
    "error_code": "010009",
    "error_message": "sql parser error: Expected option [comment], [_limiter] found [drop_after]"
}
```